# Show that the interval $[0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ is not connected when $\Bbb R$ has the topology generated by the half-open intervals $[a,b)$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the interval $[0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ is not connected when $\Bbb R$ has the topology generated by the half-open intervals $[a,b)$.

The components of this topology are the singletons. Is there a result on components I can use to conclude that $[0,2]$ cannot be connected?

I tried to approach this with assuming that $[0,2]$ is connected, but I often find it easier to assume that something isn't connected rather than something is. I couldn't get anywhere with this approach.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you want to show that a space is disconnected, it is sufficient to find two non-empty, disjoint open sets which cover the space.  In the subspace topology, both $[0,1)$ and $[1,2]$ are open.  They are nonempty and disjoint.  They cover the interval.  Is that not sufficient?  I feel like you are trying to overcomplicate things...

Comment: **Hint** You can write $[0,2]=[0,1)\cup [1,2]$, with $[0,1),[1,2]$ relatively open and disjoint.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I failed to see how is $[1,2]$ open in the subspace topology? I should be able to write it as $[a,b) \cap [0,2]$? So $[1,2) \cap [0,2] = [1,2]$?

Comment: $[1,3)\cap [0,2]=[1,2]$ is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: @SleepWalker Let $A \subseteq X$.  A set $B$ is open in $A$ if it can be written as $B = X \cap U$, where $U \subseteq X$ is open in $X$.  In this case, take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = [0,2]$, $B=[1,2]$, and $U = [1,47)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Sorgenfrey line, the arrow topology. It is totally disconnected; it might be more concrete to think about it that way. You know already that the components are the singletons: these are the **maximal** connected sets containing a given point. Therefore, take e.g. $1\in[0,2]$. Its component is $\{1\}$, and so any container set larger than $\{1\}$ is not connected (by definition of component).